# Update multiple mysql rows using R

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to update column "status" (a MySql table) with similar data frame in R.

```
ID  Status
216 1
215 1
217 1
```

I am quite able to do this with the code..

```
dbExecute(con_pratham, "Update unit_dummy set isDeleted=0 where UnitId =215")
```

But, thing is that there are so many ids that needs to update. I tried to run the same code with the for loop, but some reason only the first ids gets updates on the server.

I need suggestions/help to run the update statesmen the loop.

Comment: Because ids are randomly distributed. Now, I get the idea how can I do this. Thanks to @user8530878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the status for all the ID in a specific interval replace the query by:

```
"Update unit_dummy set isDeleted = 0 where UnitId >= 215 and UnitId < 300"
```

If the numbers are randomly distributed:

```
listID <- c(215, 200, 521, 31, 25)
dbExecute(con_pratham, paste("Update unit_dummy set isDeleted=0 where UnitId = ", paste(listID, collapse = " OR UnitID = "), sep = ""))
```

If strings:

```
listID <- c("215", "200", "521", "31", "25")
dbExecute(con_pratham, paste("Update unit_dummy set isDeleted=0 where UnitId like ", paste(listID, collapse = " OR UnitID like "), sep = ""))

listID <- c("215", "216", "217", "218", "219")
dbExecute(con_pratham, paste("Update unit_dummy set isDeleted=0 where UnitId like "21%")
```

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: Just one more suggestion, what  needs to add in the code if i  want `listId` vales in string (ex- OR UnitID = "215" OR UnitID = "216") ?

Comment: With the help of your code I manage to get this sql..   `Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in ( SOD0390306, SOD0370274, SOD0370275, SOD0370276, SOD0370277, SOD0410257, SOD0410256, SOD0410255, SOD0410258, SOD0240282, SOD0420517 )"` . only thing that is missing a sign (" ") around the each of the ids. This the R code I am using  `listID <- c(to_del$UnitCode_correct) print(paste("Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in (", paste(listID, collapse = ",'"),paste(")")))`

Comment: I missed the `sep="" ` from the syntax. It's working now.. Thanks!